# Where can I find the Linux kernel file?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions, linux-kernel

1. Is there any common directory to find kernel file in all Linux distributions?if yes please tell me how to browse to the directory?
2. Where can I find the Linux file in Ubuntu & RedHat operating systems?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There no universal standard, but the kernel is usually found in the `/boot` directory.

Comment: i found the directory and it lists many files may i know which is main kernel file?

Comment: You can use `uname -r` to find out the version you're running and then look for a file in `/boot` with that name. You can also use `cat /proc/cmdline` to find the kernel path, but note that this path is relative to the root image at boot time, so `/` likely means `/boot/` in the running system.

Comment: The path that the kernel reports that it was loaded from is relative to the root as it was at the time the kernel was loaded. That's probably called `/boot` by the time the system is fully loaded. (After the kernel has been booted, the root is "pivoted" to the normal root and the boot time root is usually called `/boot` in the run-time filesystem.)

Comment: Using cat /proc/cmdline is a better method because if you use the uname -r you will not be able to tell the difference between that kernel image or a rescue image built from the same kernel version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found "/lib/modules/<version>/kernel" folder in my Ubuntu 18.04 OS computer. Does it also contain the information of kernel?